# using MAX in MYSQL on 2 columns

Tags: mysql

I have the table `odds`:

> id | home_team | away_team | event_date | home_price | away_price | bookie | league_id

I'm trying to get a `max(home_price)`, `max(away_price)` and the bookie for each game  :

```
select max(home_price), max(away_price), bookie 
from odds where league_id=1 
group by home_team, away_team, event_date
```

I can't get it to show the right bookie for `max(home_price)` and the one for `max(away_price)`

I know I have to use "group identifier" but i cannot get i to work

The result I'm looking for is:

> max(home_price) | bookie_max_home_price | max(away_price | bookie_min_home_price

Comment: Please edit your question and include sample data and desired results.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: yes, sorry about that, here is the sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/837b0/4, what i'm trying to do is get the bookie that has the max(home_price) and the bookie with the max(away_price)

Comment: What if there are more than one bookies having, say, the same `max(away_price)` ?

Comment: that's not a problem, doesn't matter if there are 2 with the same max(away_price), i only need to print 1 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated sub-queries to get `bookie` values:

```
SELECT home_price,
       (SELECT bookie
        FROM odds AS o1
        WHERE league_id = 1 AND
              o1.home_price = o.home_price AND
              o1.home_team =  o.home_team AND
              o1.away_team =  o.away_team AND
              o1.event_date = o.event_date
        ORDER BY bookie LIMIT 1) AS bookie_home,
       away_price,
       (SELECT bookie
        FROM odds AS o2
        WHERE league_id = 1 AND
              o2.away_price = o.away_price AND
              o2.home_team =  o.home_team AND
              o2.away_team =  o.away_team AND
              o2.event_date = o.event_date
        ORDER BY bookie LIMIT 1) AS bookie_away,
       home_team, away_team, event_date         
FROM (             
  SELECT
    MAX(home_price) AS home_price, 
    MAX(away_price) AS away_price, 
    home_team, 
    away_team, 
    event_date 
  FROM odds  
  WHERE league_id = 1 
  GROUP BY home_team, away_team, event_date ) AS o
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/def6e/7)